# even with ojdbc14.jar in Build Path, Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") gets ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, jdbc, classloader

I'm trying to make an servlets application with java and oracle10g and I've had it well so far until I need some specific values from some the database, for wich I have a DAO class that handles the connection for retrieving data. I have the following issue.

First off, I excecute a `main()` method in this class that is suposed to retrieve all entries in some table an print the name of each one in console. I works perfectly.

then I want to return an ArrayList of all those names in order to use them in the servlet. So I make a method just like the one in the `main()` with the only difference that instead of printing the names, I add each one to an ArrayList which is returned after closing the conection. Well, It gets `ClassNotFoundException` in the line `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`

If it helps, I'm guided with [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-oracle-database) tutorial to connect java applications to oracle databases.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How are u making sure that the jdbc jar is in ur classpath?

Comment: At the properties of the project in eclipse, at Java Build Path option,  in the Libraries tab, Its shows "ojdbc14.jar - <ProjetctName>/lib"

Comment: Check the war contents too.

Comment: okay... the war has no jar's whatsoever. How do I put them there as well?

Answer (score 0):

Put `ojdbc14.jar` inside your war file at WEB-INF/lib/ directory. You can use ANT  [task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html) to do this. If you are unfamiliar with ANT, you can just copy the jar file inside `WEB-INF/lib/` directory under your project and just zip it using Windows explorer or `WinZip` or anything else that works for you. Then rename the .zip file to .war and deploy on Tomcat server.

If you want some quick fix just copy the `ojdbc jar` file to `server/lib` directory under tomcat and restart tomcat. It should work.

**EDIT: refer the comment below. While personally I have not seen any unexpected behavior with JDBC drivers in web-app classloader, but, it is recommended to keep driver jars under Server lib.**

Comment: Never put a database driver in a webapp classloader! Only in the server classloader.

Comment: @Michael why not? If you have different versions to support from different webapps then you will need to put in individual web apps. Can you explain more?

Comment: This has been discussed several times on the Tomcat Users Mailinglist but one reason is that the `DriverManager` is unaware of classloader hierachies and you might end up in undefined behavior. Please seach the mailing list.